# half of the electricity is out in my house. Breakers not tripped. Reset Main breaker...nothing happened.

Tags: electrical

What can be the problem? None of the breakers are tripped. halft of my house has no power. I reset the main breaker but it did not help.

Comment: Go to your breaker panel, notice how there are 2 columns of many rows of breakers.  Call the first row A, second row B, third row A, B, A, B, etc.  If you were to turn off the breakers that are not working, would they be located in every other *row* in your breaker panel?  That's a specific failure if so.

Comment: Call your power company and report partial lights out.  It's fairly common and usually on their side.

Comment: This usually means that one phase of the incoming power is missing.  The power company provides 2 phases each of 120 volts.  By combining the phases you get 240 volts (used for electric ranges and driers),  The rest of the house runs on one of the two phases.  If half of the house is out then one phase is missing. You need to call the power company.

Comment: I had the same symptoms. I reset the main breaker and it was OK again for an hour or so, but then half the lights flickered a few times and went out again. I tried resetting the main breaker again and this time I heard arcing in the main panel, so I turned it back off. I called an electrician who replaced the main breaker the next morning. There wasn't much damage to the panel from the arcing, so it did not need replacing. If I had let the arcing continue overnight, then the panel might have been damaged more. Cost was $65 for parts and $195 for labor (1 hour minimum). It would have been ~$700

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like one of the two legs feeding your house died. Inside your panel, the slots for the circuit breakers alternate like so ([full explanation of circuit breaker panels](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/46960/need-help-determining-if-a-multiwire-branch-circuit-is-wired-correctly)

[image]

Your power company will connect two wires to this box via the meter. Most likely one of the wires has gone bad. In my case, a wire between the transformer (underground) had gone out. They used something called a [dry transformer](http://www.electricservice.com/dry-type-transformers.html) to get us service on both legs until they could repair the damaged wire.